# Notification setContentIntent not working

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

```
 new Thread(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        HttpDownloadUtility.downloadFile(url,cookie, mContext, new HttpDownloadUtility.HttpDownloadListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onProgress(int progress) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "onProgress"+progress);
                                mBuilder.setProgress(100, progress, false);
                                // Displays the progress bar for the first time.
                                mNotifyManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(String file_) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "onComplete");
                                try {

                                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                                     intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                       File file = new File(file_); 
                                       intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");

                                    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MyGapActivity.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

                                    mBuilder.setContentText("Download complete")
                                            // Removes the progress bar
                                            .setProgress(0, 0, false)
                                            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download_done)
                                            .setContentIntent(pIntent);
                                    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

                                    mNotifyManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());
                                }catch (Exception e){
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onStart() {
                                Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
                                mBuilder.setContentTitle("Document Download")
                                        .setContentText("Downloading");
                                mNotifyManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onNoFile() {
                                Log.d(TAG, "onNoFile");
                                mBuilder.setContentText("No File to Download")
                                        // Removes the progress bar
                                        .setProgress(0, 0, false);
                                mNotifyManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onBegin() {
                                Log.d(TAG, "onBegin");
                                mBuilder.setContentTitle("Document Download")
                                        .setContentText("Connecting to server");
                                mNotifyManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());
                            }
                        });
                    }catch (Exception  e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        mBuilder.setContentText("Download Failed")
                                // Removes the progress bar
                                .setProgress(0, 0, false)
                                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download_done);
                        mNotifyManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());
                    }
                }
            }
// Starts the thread by calling the run() method in its Runnable
    ).start();
```

I am using the above code to download a File from the server and display the notification, But when the download is complete and if I press notification the Intent is not opening.

Is there any problem if I use the Thred class ?

The same code is given in many examples

Comment: Looks like you want `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` instead of `PendingIntent.getActivity()`.

Comment: @Sarath Babu Do you have any application installed, Which can open pdf file. As per my opinion setContentIntent not working because there is no activity available which can open PDF file.